# c# background task with class library (uwp app)

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a program which gets the information of the system and sends to the cloud system.

So, I want this program works in background task only.

I heard that I can use the class library(.dll) to make it.

What I wanna know is....

is it possible to make the dll file for background task and as the start-up task too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may run it as a Windows service. But I suggest you create a console application with the following code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    YourService service = new YourService();

    if (Environment.UserInteractive)
    {
        service.OnStart(args);
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop program");
        Console.Read();
        service.OnStop();
    }
    else
    {
        ServiceBase.Run(service);
    } 
}
```

This will be more easy to debug as you don't need to reinstall your service each time you make some changes.

Comment: In a development environment it is not necessary to reinstall the service with each build.  You simply install the service using the executable from the output directory.  You will however need to have the service stopped during a build (which can be done with a pre-build task (net stop ...))

Comment: Any way this approach makes life much easier, as you run your service in Visual Studio and have all debug tools with you.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply :) Hmm the fact is that i hope to deploy on win 10 enterprise and iot core both. That is the reason why I choose the UWP. Does the normal console application work on Win10 IoT Core too? :)